# I need to carry on validation on my spring based rest Web Service

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I know about @Valid notations in the Controller and adding different validations on my POJO object. But what about primitive data types like integers and Characters how to perform validations on them. I don't won't to create a different function or anything like that for validation. I want to use some already existing validation framework for spring. And my other problem is that if I include various validations in my POJO. Then my validation might change depending on my requirement.(i.e consider a USER pojo sometimes my request mapping might make the Id field Not Null sometime it can be null). Is there a way to separate validations from code. And depending on requirement feed the validations through an xml as in struts validation framework. Consider the following example to understand better.

Part 1 of my question:

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String name;//Sometimes I would not have any value on this. 
                        //Sometimes I might have some value on this
    @NotNull
    private int Id;

}
/*This might require a non-null value for user*/
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public createUser(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
    if (result.hasErrors()){
      // do something
    }
    else {
      // do something else
    }
}
/*This won't require a compulsory name values*/
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public createUser(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
    if (result.hasErrors()){
      // do something
    }
    else {
      // do something else
    }
}
```

Part 2 of my question:

```
//How do I validate userId in this situation?
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
User view(@PathVariable String userId){
    //do something
}
```

How do I carry on such validations and validations for primitive types using  Spring validation framework without having to create a validation class?

Comment: You can use validation groups to separate the validation use cases. But you will still need to tell manually which validation group to use. For validation on primitives types, I do not know. Basic annotations do not work on them?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer. No basic annotation when applied directly to the controller don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Part 2 In my opinion validation should be done on a service rather than on the controller. You may have some issues like this one here when validation of some arguments does not work. Probably if you add another param that is not marked as @PathVariable your validation will work. This is because you are working here on a proxy of proxy of proxy rather than a concrete component. Moving validation to services gives you some more flexibility and in my opinion a better design. In my project I do validation of primitive types as well and it work 100% with no issues.